# Meizu ubuntu / Connect to macbook per USB / Filetransfer

Tags: usb, mac, macbook

I have a new Meizu MX4 Ubuntu and it is not possible to mount the device on an macbook or imac. How I can transfer my music, photos etc. from/to the Ubuntu phone? I think this I quite very important and without this funtion the phone is almost useless.

Is there any solution or instruction for this problem? 
If not, I will give the device back.

Thank´s for your help!

Comment: there is a program "Android File Transfer" try this - https://www.android.com/intl/en_us/filetransfer/ , also what model of macbook do you have?

Comment: also what is the version of osx you are using

Comment: Thank´s for the program "Android File Transfer". It works!